# Nested column value retreiving

Tags: mysql

Need to get the subset array from the multi dimensional array as filed.The table name is items and having a column named extrafield that column contains multidimensional array.

select extra_fields,'$.*' FROM `ij4n1_k2_items` where '$.extra_fields' LIKE '"id":"22"';

[{"id":"1","value":"Mumbai"},{"id":"2","value":"USA"},{"id":"15","value":""},{"id":"3","value":""},{"id":"4","value":"

Candid photography </p>\r\n

Cinematography </p>\r\n

Pre wedding photography</p>"},{"id":"22","value":["3836","4114","4270","4961","4217","4224"]},{"id":"6","value":"https://www.weddingsutra.com/images/badge_2.png"},{"id":"7","value":"/images/vendors-img/award_img_3.jpg"},{"id":"8","value":"+91-9769090690 (Ashwin)"},{"id":"9","value":["","","new"]},{"id":"10","value":"shadesphotography@yahoo.com"},{"id":"11","value":"https://www.facebook.com/Shadesphotography"},{"id":"12","value":"https://www.instagram.com/shadesphotographyindia/"},{"id":"13","value":"https://www.pinterest.com/AshwinJhalak/"},{"id":"14","value":""},{"id":"17","value":""},{"id":"18","value":""},{"id":"19","value":""},{"id":"20","value":""},{"id":"21","value":""},{"id":"23","value":""},{"id":"24","value":""},{"id":"25","value":""},{"id":"26","value":""},{"id":"27","value":""},{"id":"28","value":""},{"id":"29","value":""}]

need to retreive
{"id":"22","value":["3836","4114","4270","4961","4217","4224"]}

Comment: Is array stored in JSON format in the extrafield column?

Comment: It is in format [{"id":"1","value":"Mumbai"},{"id":"2","value":"USA"},{"id":"15","value":""},{"id":"14","value":""}]

Comment: what is the data types of the columns- please add your table definition.

Comment: data type of column is text